# Mongodb full text search not working with exact "ANYTHING.com" Phrase

Tags: mongodb, full-text-search, mongotemplate

I am facing issue with Mongodb full text search. I have 1M data in my collection having `email` field.

I have created Text index for multiple fields. While i am using query like

> `db.user.find({"$and":[{"user_id":59856}],"$text":{"$search":"\"johnsmith@gmail.com\""}})`

Its taking more than 25 seconds.
But when i remove `.com` like

> `db.user.find({"$and":[{"user_id":59856}],"$text":{"$search":"\"johnsmith@gmail\""}})`

it takes max 3-4 seconds. I am wondering why.

Answer (score 0):

It is most likely because the dot character is treated as "match any character" in regex parlance. Since you seem to be trying to do an exact match, you can try escaping it (So that it only matches the dot character)

```
db.user.find({"$and":[{"user_id":59856}],"$text": 
{"$search":"\"johnsmith@gmail\.com\""}})
```

Comment: Thanks Bajal.
I tried same but its still taking time.
I tried below pattern

1. Taking too long time
> `db.user.find({"$and":[{"user_id":59856}],"$text": 
{"$search":"\"johnsmith@gmail\.com\""}})`

2. Working as expected
> `db.user.find({"$and":[{"user_id":59856}],"$text": 
{"$search":"\"johnsmith@gmail.in\""}})`